# Problem with parseWKT : projection mercator-2SP

Tags: geotools, mercator

1 -CoordinateReferenceSystem crss =

```
CRS.parseWKT("PROJCS[\"Mercator\",GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\","
            + "SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],"
            + "TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9108\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]],"
            + "PROJECTION[\"Mercator_2SP\"],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_1\",-33.5],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",0],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",0],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0],UNIT[\"Meter\",1]]");
```

2 - the result is:

```
PROJCS["unnamed", 
  GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
    DATUM["WGS_1984", 
      SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
      TOWGS84[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Longitude", EAST], 
    AXIS["Latitude", NORTH], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
  PROJECTION["Mercator_2SP"], 
  PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1", 33.5], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["x", EAST], 
  AXIS["y", NORTH]]
```

The problem is that the standard_parallel_1 has changed of sign; before negative after positive.
I don't understand. Could you help me?

Comment: I use Geotools : crs.parseWKT

Comment: From http://geotiff.maptools.org/proj_list/mercator_2sp.html `while in 2SP you start from the longitude of natural origin and the latitude of one of the standard parallels (the other is symmetrical in relation to the equator).` So the inverted sign is not really an error.